# What is an on-site (off-site) soliton?

Tags: soliton-theory

Could you explain to me what a **on-site** resp. **off-site** soliton is?

And maybe what is a **localized mode** and **internal mode** of a soliton?

I cannot find explanations for these notions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The authors in the following paper consider on-site and off-site solitons as part of two distinct logarithmic type non-linearity http://www.nature.com/articles/srep32990

Answer (score 0):

The "on" and "off" refer to the intensity of the soliton being focused at a grid point or inbetween adjacent grid points when you are examining discretized solitons.

See the paper *Onsite and offsite bound states of the discretenonlinear Schrödinger equation and thePeierls–Nabarro barrier* by Drs. Jenksinson and Weinstein.